# Importing CSS and HTML content in Typescript for a Web Component

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-component, native-web-component

I have a Web Component and I'm able to use it in in my main.ts which is my entry point of my application.

main.ts :

```
import './Components/List/ListComponent'

console.log("Main");
```

ListComponent.ts

```
export class ListComponent extends HTMLElement {
...
customElements.define("my-list", ListComponent );
```

I'm able to split my code into TS Modules. The next step I try to achieve is to load the HTML and CSS content for the Web Component. Similiar how Angular does it, but with Vanilla Web Components. My Goal is to define the HTML content of the Web Component in a HTML file and the CSS Style for the component in a CSS file.

The tutorial I followed uses webpack and I only want to use it for resolving my imports (I want that my TS Code is compatible with any bundler)

I've seen that I can import CSS files via `import "./css/main.css";` but it seems to only work with MiniCssExtractPlugin for webpack. Also with this the styles are global and not locally for the Web Component.
Can I import HTML files in a similar way?

Is there a "vanilla" TS way to import CSS and HTML files?
If possible I want to be independent from any Framework and Module Loader.
I know my structure is similar to Angular, but I inly need baisc functionality

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. There are babel plugins for inlining arbitrary files as strings, or you can create a file `html.d.ts` with the following contents:

```
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

Then you can do something like `import html from '. /template.html'` from your `MyList.ts`

Comment: WIth the code you provided I need a webpack html plugin or?

Comment: I wrote a Medium article - with one of the possible solutions
https://roshan-khandelwal.medium.com/web-components-c7aef23fe478

Answer (score -4):

You need to learn about JSX. In react applications template part is taken care using JSX. It's quite simple and easy to learn and use. 
Also, you will be able to import say for example `ListComponent` only if you have exported it as default other wise use {}.

`import ListComponent from './Components/List/ListComponent'`

Comment: It's a fact. But it wouldn't be a "vanilla" project anymore, I guess...

Comment: Also porting to angular would be hard?